# Update value (if it exists) in JSON from Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have an appSettings.json file in the following format

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
  ...
  },
  "appSettings": {
  ....
    "LocalVersion":  "1.0.0"
  },
  "Logging": {
    ....
  },
  "AllowedHosts": 
  ....
  }
}
```

I'm trying to write a Powershell script that will update this LocalVersion property. I need to script to 1. check if appSettings object exists, 2. check if LocalVersion property is there and 2.  Update the LocalVersion to a new value and save the file.

My script seems to be mostly working, however the writing to the file does not work. The value is getting changed in the Powershell script but not being saved to file.

```
$appSettingsPath = "C:\git\Source\src\IMStack\appsettings.json"

Write-Host "Reading JSON from " $appSettingsPath

$jsonContent = (Get-Content $appSettingsPath -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json

Write-Host $jsonContent

 if ([bool]($jsonContent.PSobject.Properties.name -match "appSettings")){
    $appSettings = $jsonContent.appSettings
    Write-Host "Found appSettings" $appSettings
    if ([bool]($appSettings.PSobject.Properties.name -match "LocalVersion")){
        $version = $appSettings.LocalVersion
        Write-Host $version
        $jsonContent.appSettings.LocalVersion= "1.1.1"
        Write-Host "Writing " $jsonContent " with " $jsonContent.appSettings " to "  $appSettingsPath
        $jsonContent | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Set-Content "appSettingsPath"
    }
 }
```

How can I save this JSON to the file?

Comment: Well you are already saving the contents here `| Set-Content "appSettingsPath"` but you're not specifying an absolute path nor an extension (`.json`). I would recommend you to take a look at this cmdlet: [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Wow, thanks, what a silly problem. I had tried Out-File before but it didn't work because my syntax was wrong with the string as you mentioned. 

        $jsonContent | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Out-File $appSettingsPath

Worked. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help :)